# Bypass login page with SQL injection

Tags: web-application, sql-injection

I am using a vulnerable webpage for practicing OWASP attacks. In the current scenario I have a login page which I am trying to bypass. I have tried Burp suite and manual cheat sheets but couldn't bypass it even though it is vulnerable. I am attaching a screenshot of the login page.

How do I bypass the login?

[image: Screenshot of login page.]

Comment: I'd suggest learning more of SQL's syntax. For testing and toying around, cheat sheets are fine, but for learning they will make you dependant and unimaginative. Also, -- can remove the AND clause, which you definitely need to do here.

Comment: on which web application you are practicing OWASP attack ?

Comment: its some private server

Comment: @AsimLiaqat this looks like a pre-made vulnerable web app for practice. Elsadek was asking which one it was.

Comment: it is not available online, it is made by one of my neighbor.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/71500/21144).

From the sql statement displayed in the image above *"and"* has precedence on *"or"*, so if the password value doesn't exists in the database, the statement will returns nothing.

What I can suggest is injecting comment symbol in the username field like this:

```
 1' or 1 = 1  --
```

Comment: I tried 1' or 1 = 1  -- in username field but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

in the picture above, all the string got escaped. try encoding and double encoding

> Alternative Expression of 'or 1 = 1'
>
> ```
> OR 'SQLi' = 'SQL'+'i'
> OR 'SQLi' > 'S'
> or 20 > 1
> OR 2 between 3 and 1
> OR 'SQLi' = N'SQLi'
> 1 and 1 = 1
> 1 || 1 = 1
> 1 && 1 = 1
> ```

You can read more here [OWASP sql injection testing sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005))

also, practice in known application like WebGoat it has hints and the solution and explain it to you